# Prevent button resizing by the number of words inside the button

Tags: html, css, button

is there any way to prevent the button resizing by the number of text characters inside the button?
I have 2 buttons with the same CSS class but the size of one of them is different because of the number of characters inside it

[image]

[image]

```
<button class="my-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
<button class="my-btn" type="button">Subscribe</button>
```

CSS:

```
.my-btn {
padding: 10px 40px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 30px;
border: 5px solid #6f97fd;

font-size: 0.8rem;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #76b3fe , #8680e4 );
}
```

Comment: give it fix width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to give it a `width`. Below I've given it 200px, you can change this to your preference.

Additionally, apply `min-width` or `max-width` if you want to ensure it doesn't go below or above a certain width.

```css
.my-btn {
padding: 10px 40px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 30px;
border: 5px solid #6f97fd;
/*change width to your preference*/
width: 200px;
font-size: 0.8rem;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #76b3fe , #8680e4 );
}
```

```html
<button class="my-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
<button class="my-btn" type="button">Subscribe</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **max-width** in **.my-btn** class

Answer (score 1):

I think `fix width` is your solution

```css
.my-btn {
padding: 10px 40px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 30px;
border: 5px solid #6f97fd;

font-size: 0.8rem;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #76b3fe , #8680e4 );
width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-btn" type="submit">Send</button>
<button class="my-btn" type="button">Subscribe</button>
```